# Images not copied to 'dist' folder in production build only with Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have an Angular 12 application that is bundled with Webpack 5.  I recently noticed that images that are specified in HTML file component templates are not copied to the output 'dist' folder when running a production build.  However, when a development build is run, the files are copied correctly into the 'dist' folder.  Below are the Webpack configuration files that are used.  The webpack-common.js file is shared by both builds.  The webpack-dev.js and webpack-prod.js files are used for development and production respectively.  The webpack-merge plugin is used to merge each with the webpack-common.js.

For example, lets say I add an image to my app.component.html file as follows:

```
<img class="my-image" src="./assets/images/my-image.png" />
```

In the development build, I will see the image in 'dist/assets/my-image.png', However, the image never makes it there in the production build.

When I observe the Network traffic in the Chrome DevTools using the development build, I see the network Request URL for the image correctly as: localhost/dist/assets/my-image.png.  However, in the production build, I see the Request URL as: localhost/app/assets/images/my-image.png, which is the original location of the file in the project folder.

What am I missing from the Webpack configuration to correct this problem for production builds?

webpack-common.js

```
module.exports = {
    output:
        {
            filename: '[name].js',
            chunkFilename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: './dist/',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]'
        }
    ,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-to-string-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'fast-sass-loader',
                        options:
                            {
                                implementation: require('node-sass')
                            }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            }          
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        mainFields: ['es2015', 'browser', 'module', 'main'],
    },
    plugins: [        
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),        
    ],
    optimization:
    {
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
            extractComments: false,
        })],
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups:
            {
                commons:
                {
                    test: /[\\/](node_modules)[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                }                                
            }
        }
    }
};
```

webpack-dev.js

```
module.exports = merge(common,
    {
        mode: 'development',
        devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
        entry:
            {            
            appbundle: './app/main.ts'
            },
        module:
            {
                rules:
                    [                                                
                        {
                            test: /\.tsx?$/,
                            use: [
                                {
                                    loader: 'cache-loader'
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'happypack/loader'
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'angular-router-loader'
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'angular2-template-loader?keepUrl=false'
                                }
                            ],
                            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "app")],
                            exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")]
                        }
                    ]
            },
        plugins:
            [                
                new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)esm5/, path.join(__dirname, './app')),                              
                new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
                    typescript: {
                        memoryLimit: 4096,
                        mode: 'write-tsbuildinfo'
                    }
                }),
                new HappyPackPlugin({
                    threads: 4,
                    loaders:
                        [
                            {
                                loader: 'ts-loader',
                                options: { transpileOnly: true, happyPackMode: true }
                            }
                        ]
                })
            ]
    });
```

webpack-prod.js

```
module.exports = merge(common,
    {
        mode: 'production',
        entry:
        {            
            appbundle: './app/main-prod.ts'
        },
        module:
        {
            rules:
                [                                       
                {
                    test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
                    use: '@ngtools/webpack',
                    include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "app")],
                    exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")]                
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins:
            [                   
                new AngularWebpackPlugin({
                    tsconfig: './tsconfig.json'
                })
            ]
    });
```